# Sprite Kit SKS file doesn't show nodes or default color

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So when I open an SKS file in XCode, it doesn't show the default color as a background. It keeps open the file I already had open instead of it, with a yellow rectangle and the simulate and zoom options at the bottom. Any nodes I try to create on the SKS file exist, but I can't see them in the editor. I can only see what I've created when I run the project.

P.S. When I double-click on the SKS file and open it in a new window, the new window says "No Editor", if this information can help in any way

Answer (score 0):

That is true, there is an issue in the editor.

However in my case, I am able to change a background for the scene,even in the editor. Perhaps your file is opened in another editor, or even in Xcode, out of project scope, close the scene in such case.

SKS file It is basically a graphical representation of a SKScene with appropriate children nodes, or SKEmitterNode node. You can give names for nodes, and access them programmatically, change their appropriate properties. 
However in case of particle editors you can see simulation even in editor

Firstly try to run simulation in the editor, perhaps you can observe any results.

Comment: No, sorry, the simulation didn't give me any results on getting my default color and my nodes visible.